# AVPlayerViewController not loading remote URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm trying to play a remote MP4 video in an `AVPlayerViewController`:

```
self.vcVideo = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
self.vcVideo.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];

[self presentViewController:self.vcVideo animated:YES completion:^{
    [self.vcVideo.player play];
}];
```

The view controller is presented but the play button is disabled:

[image: Screenshot]

This is on iOS 9.

Comment: you can alos use mpmovieplayerviewcontroller in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS9 security policy is changed. In your log you should see something about the security. I believe that your remote video url is http not https. You should add these lines to your plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```