# 'MPMoviePlayerController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, mpmovieplayercontroller, deprecated

Already someone answer this question in swift
[MPMoviePlayerController' is deprecated in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870189/mpmovieplayercontroller-deprecated-what-now) I want this in Objective-C.

I am getting this warning

> 'MPMoviePlayerController' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Here is my code :

```
MPMoviePlayerController* _moviePlayer;
_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:contentURL];
_moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: And did you look at the doc https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller that tell you what kind of object you may use to replace it?

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is in the documentation and can be easily found. You would have shown code of tries with `AVPlayerViewController` or `AVPictureInPictureController`, I wouldn't have done so. Also, in the linked question, there are 5/6 lines, which are not really complexe as the methods names are almost the same as the one in Objective-C

Comment: No you cant say duplicate because it's in swift language and I mentioned objective-c in tag.  I don't know swift, Now how to implement????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044314/avplayerviewcontroller-not-loading-remote-url then ?

Comment: The language is completely irrelevant here. This is a question about the framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of @Larme I resolved my Issue.
1) I added two frameworks

```
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

2) I replace my code with

```
AVPlayerViewController * _moviePlayer1 = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _moviePlayer1.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_img.contentURL];

    [self presentViewController:_moviePlayer1 animated:YES completion:^{
        [_moviePlayer1.player play];
    }];
```

I hope it will help who ever face this issue .

Comment: It is possible to play youtube video's...?

Comment: No For youtube videos you need to use webView. Here is the link, please check https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper